# Idempotent operator on Hilbert space with operator norm $1$ is projection?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I know there are many solutions on Stack Exchange, I checked all the solutions but I want a different solution in my approach.
My approach is to show as $E$ is idempotent so $h=(h-Eh)+Eh$, now I want to show
$$\operatorname{dist}(h,\operatorname{ran}E)=\lVert h-Eh\rVert$$
in order to show $E$ is orthogonal projection. I am stuck on how to show it using that the operator norm of $E$ is $1$ and idempotency of $E$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\|Ex\|^2=\langle E^*Ex,Ex\rangle \le \|E^*\|\|Ex\|^2=\|Ex\|^2$$ which means  an equality holds  in the Cauchy-Schwarz  inequality. Therefore $E^*Ex=Ex.
$ This implies $$\langle Ex,x-Ex\rangle=\langle (I-E^*)Ex,x\rangle =0$$ Hence $Ex\perp x-Ex.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $V= Range (E)$. It is relatively easy to show that two vectors $x,y \in H$ are perpendicular iff for any scalar $λ$ in $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$),
$$ \|x+\lambda y\|  \ge \|x\| .$$
Since every point of $V$ is of the form $λy$ for some scalar $λ$ and $y \in V$,  we see that  $dist(x, V) = \| x - Ex\|$ if and only if
$$   \|x-Ex\| \le \|x+\lambda y\| \tag 1 , ~~~ \forall \lambda \in \mathbb R , \forall y \in V. $$
Write $x=v+z$ where $v \in V$ and $z \in \ker E$ so that $x-Ex=z$. Then $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$ z \bot V .\tag 2$$
Since $\|E\|=1$, for any $y \in V$ and any scalar $\lambda$,
$$ \|y \| = \| E(y +λz)\| \le \|y + \lambda z\| ,$$
so that $y \bot z$. This shows that $z \bot V$ and proves $(2)$.